# Add a custom Ribbon group to an existing OOB Sharepoint Ribbon tab at run time

Tags: sharepoint, ribbon

How can I Add a custom Ribbon group to an existing OOB Sharepoint Ribbon tab at run time?

I have a custom web part and I want to add a custom group to Ribbon.Documents Contextual tab at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provision tab definition using custom actions, and then in you server code use SPRibbon.MakeContextualGroupInitiallyVisible and SPRibbon.MakeTabAvailable to show up you tab.
Also you can use CKS.Dev extension for visual studio it contains templates which have some markup and code to help you to start.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I actually needs to add a group to already existing Documents tab not to create a new custom one

Comment: @AHMEDRABEE if you need to add group to already existing sharepoint tab then CustomActions will help you,  just set location attribute to needed tab id. You can examine cmdui.xml in 14 hive for standart sharepoint tabs and groups

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I need to add a Group at run time not a declarative custom Action

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to create buttons. Here is the helpful link

http://www.ro.umt.com/blog/2013/11/14/creating-sharepoint-ribbon-elements-in-javascript/

if you look at the createTab() function you see you can create new group using this function CUI.Group .

Comment: Please [provide the relevant sections of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).